# Obtener la ruta del directorio en python, pero en una carpeta antes?

Tags: python, rutas

estoy trabajando en un proyecto, y quiero dejar todo muy automático sin tener rutas de carpetas de Windows fijas.
Por ejemplo si tengo la ruta: C:\Proyectos\Compactacion\principal.
Normalmente para obtetener la ubicacion de "principal", he trabajado para obtener la ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
dir_actual = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Pero en esta ocasión quisiera tener la ruta, hasta la carpeta anterior, es decir, en el ejemplo hasta "compactación".
¿Cómo podría hacerlo sin dejar rutas fijas?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Si quieres por ejemplo acceder a un archivo una carpeta atrás y el directorio de trabajo es el directorio del script, alcanza con `../carpeta/archivo.txt` usando paths relativos. Donde .. significa "una carpeta atrás"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe haber un montón de alternativas, pero esta me acomoda:

```
import os

separador = os.path.sep
dir_actual = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
dir = separador.join(dir_actual.split(separador)[:-1])
print(dir)
```

`os.path.sep` nos da el separador de archivos usado en la plataforma actual, que sería "/" para Linux y "\" para Windows.

El resto es separar el path en sus componentes con `split`, descartar el último componente (el subdirectorio actual) y volver a armar el path usando `join`.

Comment: Y "\" para windows. Se comió la barra usted, don Moe.

Comment: @Benito-B. Resulta impresentable que en un sitio donde se reunen a los mejores programadores del mundo tengamos que sufrir un editor de porquería que ya era obsoleto hace 20 años atrás.

Comment: Hola Candid moe, Excelente funciona perfecto y es justo lo que necesito.  Muchas gracias